# How Do I model a Shipment From One City (source) To Another (destination) is Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

I working in Rails 3 Activerecord. I have two models City and Shipment and I'm trying to model a shipment leaving from one city (ship_from) and shipping to another (ship_to).  This is what I have:

```
class Shipment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ship_from, :class_name => "City", :foreign_key => "city_id"
  belongs_to :ship_to, :class_name => "City", :foreign_key => "city_id"
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ship_froms
  has_many :ship_tos
end
```

I know I missing something very simple and obvious, but I'm just not getting it. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're modeling two one-to-many relations. You're saying as Shipment has one `from` city and one `to` city.

The one side is the part that's saved in your table. So you're saving a `from_city_id` and a `to_city_id` in your shipments table. Both these columns contain the id of a City.

You model this one city relation by adding the following code in the Shipment class:

```
belongs_to :from_city, :class_name => 'City'
```

This code means we have a property `from_city` which type is `City` (from option :class_name, default would be FromCity). You can find the City by searching the table cities for `id = from_city_id` (id is the default for the option :primary_key, :from_city_id is the default for :foreign_key).

For the to_city you declare

belongs_to :to_city, :class_name => 'City'

The many part of the relation is in the `City` class. To say you have many Shipments from this city. You declare the following:

```
many :from_shipments, :class_name => 'Shipment', :foreign_key => 'from_city_id'
```

The code means we have a property `from_shipments` which type is a collection of `Shipment`s (:class_name). You can find the Shipment by searching in the  table shipments for `from_city_id = id` (we override the default city_id by declaring a :foreign_key)

For the to_city you declare

```
many :to_shipments, :class_name => 'Shipment', :foreign_key => 'to_city_id'
```

More info about the defaults and options for belongs_to, has_one, has_many can be found [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html).

Comment: Thanks so much. I think I am following but I'm not quite all the way there.  In my Shipment model do I explicitly create columns for from_shipment and to_shipment such that the shipment model/table would have: shipment_id, to_shipment, from_shipment.

Comment: You only need 2 columns in your shipments table. A from_city_id (containing the id of the city you're shipping from) and a to_city_id (containing the id of the city you're shipping to. The referred column id on the cities table already exists.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store this "ship_from"/"ship_to" relationship in the database for this to work. Otherwise there is no way of knowing this from the state of the database.

Assuming a many-to-many relationship here (since you don't want to be duplicating cities info), you would need a joining model/table, for example:

```
class ShipmentLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Fields:
  # - shipment_id
  # - city_id
  # - location_type
  #   => this can be either "SOURCE" or "DESTINATION"

  belongs_to :shipment
  belongs_to :city

  # TODO: add a validation to ensure that multiple sources/destinations are not added!
end
```

Then, in your `Shipment` model you can have something like:

```
has_many :shipment_locations

has_one :source, 
        :through => :shipment_locations,
        :source => :city,
        :conditions => { :location_type => "SOURCE" }
```

NOTE: this is not fully tested, and the left is rest as an exercise for the OP :)